# How to extract values from pandas Series without index

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have the following when I print my data structure:

```py
print(speed_tf)

44.0   -24.4
45.0   -12.2
46.0   -12.2
47.0   -12.2
48.0   -12.2
Name: Speed, dtype: float64
```

I believe this is a pandas Series but not sure

I do not want the first column at all I just want

```py
-24.4
-12.2
-12.2
-12.2
-12.2
```

I tried `speed_tf.reset_index()`

```py
  index  Speed
0 44.0   -24.4
1 45.0   -12.2
2 46.0   -12.2
3 47.0   -12.2
4 48.0   -12.2
```

How can I just get the Speed values with index starting at 0?

Comment: From your last line, you can go one more step: `speed_tf.reset_index()["Speed"]`... though I bet there's a nicer way.

Comment: "I believe this is a pandas Series but not sure" It's always nice to be sure. Try:
`print(type(speed_tf))`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
speed_tf.values
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: This solution provides a list, whereas the other solution provides a DataFrame.

Comment: @CedricZoppolo First, this solution provides a numpy array, not a list, but secondly, I am not sure what to make of your comment. Do you view this as a good or a bad thing?

Comment: You are right. `values` outputs an `array` type. I was just pointing out the difference of outputs between these two solutions. I believe none of them is better than the other. It depends on further implementation you may need.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use [`Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and [`Series.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = speed_tf.reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

   Speed
0  -24.4
1  -12.2
2  -12.2
3  -12.2
4  -12.2
```

Answer (score 5):

To print only the Speed values, with no indices:

```
print(speed_tf.to_string(index=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone willing to create a dataframe having 2 columns: series indices and series values.

```py
# firstColumnName you choose to give
df = pd.DataFrame({'firstColumnName': speed_tf.index, 'Speed': speed_tf.values})
```